Selenium Automation Issue: Input Field Only Accepting First Value
I'm facing an issue with my Selenium automation script in Python. Until yesterday, everything was working perfectly. However, today, the script is not behaving as expected.
The problem is with a function that inputs a CPF (Brazilian ID number) into a form field. Although the CPF value is correctly updated in the code, the automation only inputs the first value into the field. When the script tries to enter a new CPF, only the first value is displayed, regardless of the new values being passed.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
def inserir_cpf(self, cpf):
    print(f" Inside the Insert CPF function: {cpf}")
    campo_cpf = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'documentNumber'))
    )
    campo_cpf.clear()  # Clears the field before inserting the new value
    campo_cpf.send_keys(cpf)
    self.simular() 


def filtrar_cpf(self):
    t = 0
    while t < len(doc.dic_cpf):
        print(t)
        cpf = doc.list_cpf[t]
        print('Selecting CPF')
        print(cpf)
        self.list_banco = ['BMP', 'QI', 'J17']

        for i in self.list_banco:
            print('Selecting Bank')
            print(i)
            bot.escolher_banco(i)
            bot.inserir_cpf(cpf)

            saldo_armazenado = bot.armazenar_saldo(cpf)

            if saldo_armazenado:
                print('Balance stored')
                break
            else:
                print('Balance not found')

        t += 1

Here is an example, the prints show that the values are being updated correctly.
What I've Tried
Clearing the field before sending keys:
campo_cpf.clear()
Ensuring the field is clickable:

campo_cpf = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'documentNumber'))
)

Inserting value character by character with a delay:
for char in cpf:
    campo_cpf.send_keys(char)
    time.sleep(0.1)

Ensuring the field is empty before sending keys:
while campo_cpf.get_attribute('value') != '':
    campo_cpf.clear()

None of these attempts have resolved the issue. The automation still only inputs the first value into the field.
Additional Information
The field in question is identified by By.NAME, 'documentNumber'.
The function self.simular() is called after sending keys, but the issue persists even if this function is commented out.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I found a solution. I added a while loop inside the function that inserts the value into the field. This field uses the backspace key to delete any existing value and then inserts the CPF. See you later.
The solution within the code:
def inserir_cpf(self, cpf):
    print(f" Inside the Insert CPF function: {cpf}")
    campo_cpf = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        ec.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'documentNumber'))
    ) 

    while cpf_field.get_attribute('value') != '':
    cpf_field.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)

    campo_cpf.clear()  # Clears the field before inserting the new value
    campo_cpf.send_keys(cpf)
    self.simular() 

